# Sailjs and Mysql test using sails-mysql

Tags: mysql, sails.js, crud

I am trying to simply connect to a remote database using sails, via sails-mysql.

```
sails new sql
cd sql
npm install sails-mysql
```

I then move to the config files:

```js
// config/adapters.js

module.exports.connections = {
  mysql: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX',
    user: 'name',
    password: 'secret',
    database: 'test'
  }
};
```

Then in my /api/models/user.js

```js
module.exports = {

  schema: true,
  autoCreatedAt: false,
  autoUpdatedAt: false,
  connection: 'mysql',
  tableName: 'test1',
  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    }
  }
};
```

I have subsequently set up a database test and table test1 on my remote host (and allowed all access). 
If I then send a query in my browser

```
 http://localhost:1337/user/create?name=user1&password=pass1
```

It fails, but the chrome console doesn't help much at all. It does however work when I use the localhostdb provided by sails?

I have manually added some names and passwords to my database to, but I know no way of querying it. My question comes down to this. Can anyone give me some guidance on how Sails, Mysql and sails-mysql interact? for example, could someone show me how to i) connect to a database correctly, and ii) interact with it using models, controllers in sails with basic CRUD operations. How would I signup a user, add him to my database, and allow him to update his name? Thanks a Stack!

Comment: What error is being shown in the console. that you life your sails.js app in?

Comment: I have found my problem and will post an example shortly

Comment: @ mathew Waiting for your example :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how it is done.

```
sails new sql
cd sql
npm install sails-mysql
```

as shown above. Now generate a new user api.

```
sails generate api user
```

The files of concern are api/controllers/UserController.js, api/models/User.js, config/connections.js and create a new file called views/new.ejs that looks like this

views/new.ejs

```html
<form action="/user/create" method="POST">  
    <h2> Create an account</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name">  
    <input type="submit" value="Create Account"/>
</form>
```

Now update your UserController.js

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res){
   'use strict';
    res.view('new.ejs');
  } 
};
```

Save everything and you can "sails lift" and point your browser to localhost:1337/user and you will see the form (nothing will work)

Update your User.js model. You'll notice the POST action is calling user/create. This create function is shown in our User.js.

Notice the User.create line below.User = user model (sails does this for us) create = a waterline feature enabling us to save time and not use MySQL.

```
module.exports = {
    index: function(req, res){
   'use strict';
    res.view('new.ejs');
  }
    create: function(req, res) {  
    User.create(req.params.all(), function userCreated(err, user) {
        return res.redirect('/user/new');  
     }
     res.redirect('user/show/' + user.name);
    });
  },    
};
```

Update your config/connections.js as described above

```
module.exports.connections = {
  mysql: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'XXX.XX.XXX.XXX',
    user: 'name',
    password: 'secret',
    database: 'test'
  }
};
```

Now the most important thing to do is config your MySQL properly, this is where I was battling.

Because the MySQL host is not local you need to log onto it either via ssh or through phpMyAdmin. Make a database 'test' and add a table 'tbl_users'

Then you need to allow permission to access the database from your local IP with something like this.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'XXX.XXX.XX.XXX'WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

That easy.

The edit follow the same principle, watch these videos for more help: http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts

I am sure everyone will be doing it different ways, so post your questions/suggestions and we'll get them solved.